# NameValueCollection key without value

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

I have a `NameValueCollection` variable `queryDict`.

Some of the keys have no values. However I would like to go through all keys, even if they have no values associated to them.

Using this, I get null instead of the key name if value is empty:

```
foreach (var parameter in queryDict)
{
  key = (string)parameter;
}
```

`AllKeys` produce all the results.

However I also get `null`. Looking at the content of `queryDict`, I can see with the string the value is there...

So how can I access all the key name without needing to create an algorithm?

**Addition:**

Here is the content of queryDict when hovering with the mouse:

{AQB=1&ndh=1&cid.&oxygenid}

cid. and oxygenid aren't found in the loop

I filled it this way:

```
string queryString = "AQB=1&ndh=1&cid.&oxygenid";
NameValueCollection queryDict = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
```

Comment: A NameValueCollection allows you to add more than one value with the same key, but if you add a key with a null value and then readd again the same key with a not null value, the first one is no more available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A NameValueCollection allows you to add more than one value with the same key, but if you add a key with a null value and then readd again the same key with a not null value, the first value (the null one) is no more available

Let's test some scenarios:

```
NameValueCollection coll = new NameValueCollection();
coll.Add("This", "Test");
coll.Add("That", "A value");
coll.Add("This", "Not a null");

foreach (string p in coll.AllKeys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key=" + p + ", Value=[" + (coll[p] ?? "null") + "]");
}
```

we get, as output,

```
Key=This, Value=[Test,Not a null]
Key=That, Value=[A value]
```

So the object has merged the values of the two adds in a single entry separating the two values with a comma. 
Now let's try with

```
coll.Add("This", null);
coll.Add("That", "A value");
coll.Add("This", "Not a null");
```

The output is

```
Key=This, Value=[Not a null]
Key=That, Value=[A value]
```

There is no trace of the first add. Why this happens? Simply because the internal logic of the Add method that merges the values cannot distinguish between the initial value of null and the null added by the first add. So it just replace the null value with the "Not a null" string.

Indeed commenting the last add

```
coll.Add("This", null);
coll.Add("That", "A value");
// coll.Add("This", "Not a null");
```

we get

```
Key=This, Value=[null]
Key=That, Value=[A value]
```

Comment: thanks for this explanation. I tried this code and you are right. It then seems it is due to the way I fill it (I made an addition to my post). Is there a way to use ParseQueryString so parameters without values are not ignored?

Comment: Well, ParseQueryString will treat parameters without values as empty strings ("") not as a null values. So yes, it returns the key with an empty string if there is no value. But your sample input is not valid. To work correctly with ParseQueryString you should have _"AQB=1&ndh=1&cid=&oxygenid=";_

Comment: In particular this explain some of your problem better. When you pass the string _"AQB=1&ndh=1&cid.&oxygenid"_ to ParseQueryString you get a third key in your collection "null" with two strings as value "cid." and "oxygenid". This seems to indicate that ParseQueryString is unable to determine the key and use the input just as values for a null key.

Comment: thx for all the help!! it's kinda bad that I have to do it this way... it's not hard but I would expect parsequerstring to return the parameters

Comment: I am not an expert but to be considered a parameter in a querystring your need the =

Comment: thanks for the precision!! may I ask what is considered .oxyid then? What is the point of it??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156602/discussion-between-steve-and-cher).

Answer (score 0):

`I would like to go through all keys` You should loop through the keys then:

```
foreach (var parameter in queryDict.Keys)
```

Comment: what I did is the same. I still don't get the key that don't have parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works. You can loop through keys using  `NameValueCollection.AllKeys` without any duplicate returned.

```
foreach (var parameter in queryDict.AllKeys) { key = parameter; }
```

Comment: it doesn't return the keys for which values are null either. It does the same as what I do.

Comment: You might have `null keys` in the object. `NameValueCollection` allows duplicate/null keys. Otherwise, this should work.

Comment: The key isn't null. I will add in a minute the content of the queryDict

Answer (score 0):

Use ?? null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Comment: thanks!! may I ask where do I write this in the code??